# Function of bounded variation and a positive constant

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $c>0$ be a positive constant and $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ a function of bounded variation on the interval $[a,b]$. How do you prove that $g(x) = c^f(x)$ is of bounded variation?

Comment: Try splitting it into the cases k<1 and k>1 (obviously k=1 is trivial) then base off the fact that k^x is strictly increasing or decreasing

Answer (score 0):

First show that $f$ is *bounded*; say $|f(x)|\le A$ for all $x$. Now show that there exists $c$  such that  $$|k^s-k^t|\le c|s-t|$$for $|s|,|t|\le A$ (for example by the Mean Value Theorem) and you're done...

Comment: I thought of doing that, using that fact it would be an absolutely continuous function, but how do you find c? Suppose k=5, how would you do it?

Comment: Using the fact that _what_ is absolutely continuous? I don't see any AC functions here. How do you find $c$? Exactly as I  said. You know the Mean Value Theorem, right?